# changing data in array

Tags: php

I would like to add `fruits/` to the beginning of all of the values in an array.

How can I do this?

For example - array before:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => apple/mango
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => orange/strawberries
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => orange/strawberries
    ) 
)
```

Array after:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => fruits/apple/mango
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => fruits/orange/strawberries
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [fruits] => fruits/orange/strawberries
    ) 
)
```

Is the solution the `.=` operator?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and an anonymous function (requires PHP >= 5.3):

```
$array = array_map(function($item) {
                       return array('fruits' => 'fruits/'.reset($item));
                   }, $array);
```

It's slightly harder than it could be, since your input array is of the form

```
$array = array(
    array('fruits' => 'apple/mango'),
    array('fruits' => 'orange/strawberries'),
);
```

while it seems it could also have been

```
$array = array(
    'apple/mango',
    'orange/strawberries',
);
```

You can do the same in a slightly more cumbersome way for PHP < 5.3 -- if you need this, please leave a comment.